# Adding navigation bar to multiple html pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I am working on a full stack(MERN stack) project to create a job portal. I want to add a navigation bar to all the pages which can be used to route to corresponding pages. I have already created the navigation bar using html and css. Should I add the code into all the pages in the project or is there any other way. Also how will the route.js file be if add the navigation bar code in all the pages (should I make a route.js file for each page?).
I have the following pages: Home, About, Contact, Jobs, Login/signup, Companies, Profile.

I tried to add the navigation bar code in all the html pages and used a client side routing, but was not able to use server side functions such as authentication. I want a navigation bar that can help to route between pages along with checking the authentication.

Comment: you said you working on MERN stack project. right? then just make a nav component and use that nav component in layout.js. assuming you are using NextJs

Comment: This is my first mern project, and I am weak in using react, so I didn't really use any react components. Could you please explain on how to do so?

Comment: if it's your first project I would Like to suggest you to make a short project on react/nextjs it won't take that much time to learn. I guess 2 to 4 hours would be more than enough to learn nextjs basics. you can watch youtube tutorials. or you connect with me over some other sns. I can guide you over chat.

Comment: ok, I'll first work on react. thanks for the advice.

Comment: I've also answered your question. you can look into it to get the basic idea of how nextjs works and how to create nav in nextjs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

here is sample tutorial on how to create a navbar in nextJs app.
run these commands in terminal

```
cd ~project
npx create-next-app@latest
```

after running these commands you will be asked these questions

```
What is your project named? my-app
Would you like to use TypeScript? No / Yes
Would you like to use ESLint? No / Yes
Would you like to use Tailwind CSS? No / Yes
Would you like to use `src/` directory? No / Yes
Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) No / Yes
Would you like to customize the default import alias? No / Yes
```

don't use typescript if you are beginner so select no.
rest of others select yes
use ESLint
use tailwind
use src directory
use App router
default import alias

then your main project directory structure should look something like this

```
src
  app
     layout.js
     page.js
```

in `src` make a directory named `Components` and in `Components` create a new `Nav.js`
inside `Nav.js` write code for your navbar something like this

```
import Link from "next/link";
export default function Navbar() {
     return (
   <header className="bg-white">
            <div className="mx-auto flex h-16 max-w-screen-xl items-center gap-8 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
              <Link className="block text-teal-600" href="/">
                <span className="sr-only">Home</span>
                Logo
              </Link>
              <div className="flex flex-1 items-center justify-end md:justify-between">
                <nav aria-label="Global" className="hidden md:block">
                  <ul className="flex items-center gap-6 text-sm">
                    <li>
                      <Link className="text-gray-500 transition hover:text-gray-500/75" href="/">
                        About
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <Link className="text-gray-500 transition hover:text-gray-500/75" href="/">
                        Careers
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <Link className="text-gray-500 transition hover:text-gray-500/75" href="/">
                        History
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <Link className="text-gray-500 transition hover:text-gray-500/75" href="/">
                        Services
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <Link className="text-gray-500 transition hover:text-gray-500/75" href="/">
                        Projects
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <Link className="text-gray-500 transition hover:text-gray-500/75" href="/">
                        Blog
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
                <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
                  <div className="sm:flex sm:gap-4">
                    <Link className="block rounded-md bg-teal-600 px-5 py-2.5 text-sm font-medium text-white transition hover:bg-teal-700" href="/">
                      Login
                    </Link>
                    <Link className="hidden rounded-md bg-gray-100 px-5 py-2.5 text-sm font-medium text-teal-600 transition hover:text-teal-600/75 sm:block" href="/">Register
                    </Link>
                  </div>
                  <button className="block rounded bg-gray-100 p-2.5 text-gray-600 transition hover:text-gray-600/75 md:hidden">
                    <span className="sr-only">Toggle menu</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </header>
     );
    }
```

make sure to use  instead of  tag.

next go to `src > app` and create a new folder with the name you want that page  like contact and 1 more folder with name services or create whatever you want it to be. and the folder structure should look like this.

```
src
   app
      layout.js
      page.js
      contact
         page.js
      services
         page.js
      anything-else
         page.js
  Components
      Nav.js
```

your page.js should look something like this

```
export default function page() {
  return (
<div>
<h1>Title : Contact us page</h1>
</div>
  );
}
```

and now replace the "/" in  's href with the folder name that you created in app directory.  i.e, contact and service

something like this

```
<Link className="text-gray-500 transition hover:text-gray-500/75" href="/contact">
                        contact
                      </Link>
```

and now the final step.

import the Nav component in Layout the js

it should look something like this

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html
      lang="en"
    >
      <body>
        <Nav/>
{children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```